# Softlayer location conflict for port speeds

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202225/new-items-for-softlayer-virtual-server-order)

But now I got a new message:

> 10 Gbps Private Network Uplink cannot be ordered with location Amsterdam 1 on this package.

I tried 253 package and looked at location conflicts. What I got for this item(3957 id) is:

```
[
{
    "itemId"=>3957,
    "message"=>"10G connections cannot be ordered in dal01",
    "packageId"=>"",
    "resourceTableId"=>3
},
{
    "itemId"=>3957,
    "message"=>"10G connections cannot be ordered in hou02",
    "packageId"=>"",
    "resourceTableId"=>142775
}
```

]

I've seen that 10gps uplinks are conflicts for many datacenter, but I don't see that this particular item is one for Amsterdam 1. I wonder if there is one more place for conflicts to look at?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really sure that you are using an **ObjectFilter** to get the result.

Currently there is an issue for itemLocationConflicts with the ObjectFilter, that's the reason why your are not able to see all the conflicts for itemId: 3957 (The fix of this issue could take some time), so I recommend not use the objectFilter

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/253/getItemLocationConflicts
```

> There is a location conflict for item: 3957 with Amsterdan 1

```
{
    "itemId": 3957,
    "packageId": 253,
    "resourceTableId": 168642
}
```

My apologies for the inconveniences, I will update this forum when the issue has been solved

Comment: I use the ruby API and what I did is:
client['Product_Package'].object_mask('mask[itemLocationConflicts]').object_with_id(package_id).getObject

switched to that below and I got all conflicts listed:
client['Product_Package'].object_with_id(package_id).getItemLocationConflicts

Comment: That's right. I added this info into the issue reported